# Error occurs when importing {useAnimationFrame} from "framer-motion";

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I get an error when I try to import useAnimationFrame from framer-motion,

At the moment, I am using **framer motion** version : *"4.1.17"*

Is there something I am doing wrong,

I will appreciate a solution to this.

[image]

Below is a snippet of my code :

```js
import React from "react";
import Type from "../components/Type";
import Atom from "../img/atom.png";
import Down from "../img/down-chevron.png";
import Temi from "../img/temisanren.png";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useAnimationFrame } from "framer-motion";

export const HeroSection = () => {

    const ref = useRef(null);

    useAnimationFrame((t) => {
        const rotate = Math.sin(t / 10000) * 200;
        const y = (1 + Math.sin(t / 1000)) * -50;
        ref.current.style.transform = `translateY(${y}px) rotateX(${rotate}deg) rotateY(${rotate}deg)`;
    });

    return (
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="cube" ref={ref}>
                            <div className="side front" />
                            <div className="side left" />
                            <div className="side right" />
                            <div className="side top" />
                            <div className="side bottom" />
                            <div className="side back" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
    );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `useAnimationFrame` was added in version 5.4.0, see https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#540-2021-12-06

Comment: oh! okay. I will therefore have to update my frama-motion to version 5.4.0. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you're updating better update to latest, which is `6.5.2`, but that might be a bit more difficult depending on how many breaking changes were made from v4 to v6.

Comment: @Enve, I downgraded my version to version *4.1.17* because of the bugs in version *5.4.0*. What's the probability that version *6.5.0* will be bug-free, have you tried it before?.